# Implementation of Restricted Boltzmann Machines?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

A [Restricted Boltzmann Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine) is a classical and basic neural net method in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning.

We can easily find implementation in Matlab or Python, but are there any implementations in the Wolfram language?

Both official and personal implementations are welcome.

Comment: A quick google returned this implementation from Sanjit Singh Batra and Taliesin Beynon that seems to have been completed at a Wolfram summer school: [GitHub: Restricted Boltzmann Machines in Mathematica](https://github.com/sanjitsbatra/Wolfram-Summer-School).

Comment: Great, glad to know that, thanks. @MarcoB